# Get rid of horizontal box shadow even if it's 0

Tags: css, clip

Even if I set the box-shadow horizontal value 0 it gives plus width to the div.
How can I get rid of those extra pixels if the element width is not known or it's set to 100%?

I've found [this](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=301) method that uses the CSS clip property, but it only works if the elements width is known in pixels.

I could calculate the pixels with jquery/javascript and then use that value, but I'm sure that there is a simpler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a wrapper, float it and then set `overflow: hidden`.

```
#wrapper {
  float: left;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is a demo
http://jsfiddle.net/n8LWF/

Answer (score 0):

W3C give you the answer

```
<shadow> = inset? && [ <length>{2,4} && <color>? ]
...
The fourth length is a spread distance. Positive values cause the shadow shape to expand in all directions by the specified radius. Negative values cause the shadow shape to contract.
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow

You have 4 properties in box shadow. 
And like this you can have shadow on 3 side only:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 20px -5px black;
```